# Bootstrap collapse isn't working; hamburger menu not showing up

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am making an Angular application, and installed all my libs with Bower. When I check the console, all the sheets/scripts are loading up properly. I also have bootstrap and jQuery defined in my head. I copied the code from Bootstrap's site.

The issue that I'm having is that the hamburger menu never comes up. The links just stay exactly the same as when the screen is big. The other problem is that nothing in the nav-collapse collapse div shows up, even when the site is big. Seems like there is an issue with collapse, which is making both not work. Suggestions?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Jay - Web Developer</title>

    <!-- For Angular Routing -->
    <base href='/'>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/libs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="assets/libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/libs/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/libs/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <!-- APP -->
    <script src="app/controllers/mainCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.routes.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="jayPortfolio" ng-controller="mainController as main">

  <!-- NAVBAR -->
  <header>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
          <div class="container">
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
              <span class="icon-bar">About</span>
              <span class="icon-bar">Portfolio</span>
              <span class="icon-bar">Experience</span>
              <span class="icon-bar">Contact</span>
            </a>

            <a class="brand" href="#">JAY</a>

            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
              work please
            </div>

          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Obviously you've modified the navbar from what you copied from the Bootstrap site. Have you tried a direct copy/paste? No console errors?

Comment: I see a dramatic change to the hamburger menu markup above. You've added text where I wouldn't expect to see text. The `icon-bar` elements create the hamburger menu and should be left alone.

Comment: I tried a direct copy/paste, but it didn't work. No errors in the console.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The markup of your navbar is not correct. The markup should be as follows:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Huisje Thuisje</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <!-- Put here your menu items -->
            </ul>

        </div --><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
</nav>
```

In the `ul` element, place the menu items. That should do the trick. See also the [documentation page](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar).

Answer (score 1):

in my case, my newly created laravel project hamburger menu is not working, so go to  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/ and coppy the 3 js link and add to your header.

Comment: It's a good idea to write up a detailed answer, address the "why" around it and then give the links as suggestion

Comment: please use question code and write a good answer. you can use this link for improve your answer  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

Copy the **Javascript** link from the **bootstrap** site and paste it in your HTML file. It will work just fine!

Answer (score 1):

This website, which is about the hamburger menu icon helped me. The URL is https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/b4/jquery/navigation/hamburger-menu/. It shows you a complete coding, which may help. You may have to change the colour of the hamburger menu icon to make it visible against a dark colour. I typed

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light light-blue lighten-4">.
```

For the span tag, I put in

```
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon navbar-dark"></span>
```

because when you type navbar-dark, the hamburger menu icon appears light coloured and vice versa with navbar-light.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is more like this for the `container` part:

```
<div class="container">
        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>

        <a class="brand" href="#">JAY</a>

        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
             <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Experience</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Tried this. Did not work for whatever reason. Syntax looks right.

Answer (score 0):

So for me the I had the same problem and the issue was that the cdns i used was:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-xNzN2a4ltkB44Mc/Jz3pT4iU1cmeR0FkXs4pru/JxaQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

which was necessary for ajax to work
and this was in the footer section
so I left this here for the ajax to work and had the following script cdns in the header section and the bootstrap collapse was working fine:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Boostrap 5 users.

1.JS link is not included

```
<body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

2.Navigation bar list elements not listed inside `<div class='collapse navbar-collapse'>`

3.Without the div's `id`  matching with the  `aria-control` value, despite the JS link, the nav-items won't show up in the drop down.